# How to get a web browser without one

Tags: browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I download and install a browser on a new installation of Windows 7E?](https://superuser.com/questions/12786/how-can-i-download-and-install-a-browser-on-a-new-installation-of-windows-7e)

If my only web browser is no working, is there a way to get another one using only the computer in question (i.e. don't use someone else's computer)? In this hypothetical situation the computer is running a clean install of Windows 7, so there aren't any OEM programs installed.

Comment: I couldn't find an identical question. @random do you care to list a few for us?

Comment: Apart from the link mentioned at the top of the question? @jan

Comment: @random the answers here were much more helpful, because the community consensus in the other question was, "you don't need to download a browser". This question is different, because you do need to download a browser. If you didn't close it we might have had a good answer for downloading chrome installer, for example. I found this helpful: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/PY0FXJ26HJ4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Windows 7, as you mention, you can open My Computer and in the address bar type in :

`ftp://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera` (Opera Browser)

or

`ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub` (Firefox)

You can then navigate the folders and find the version that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the ISV's FTP site with the `ftp` command line client and download it that way.