# How to install a browser without a browser

Tags: windows-7, browser

Sevral years ago, I uninstalled every one of my internet browsers on a laptop running Windows 7 Home Premium version 6.1.7601, installed in 2011.

I now want to install a browser - any browser - onto the laptop. However, I can't figure out how to install a browser without having a browser.

Internet Explorer is completely uninstalled. FTP commands through Windows Explorer (such as found in question 302602) are not working either.
I used to have Chrome as well as Firefox, but those were both completely uninstalled.

My laptop has good internet connection, and can run Outlook and many programs (though not all) when it is in a good mood.

NOT A DUPLICATE OF:

[How can I download and install a browser on a new installation of Windows 7E?](https://superuser.com/questions/12786/how-can-i-download-and-install-a-browser-on-a-new-installation-of-windows-7e)
- that refers to Windows 7E and the solution doesn't work on my version.

[How to get a web browser without one](https://superuser.com/questions/302602/how-to-get-a-web-browser-without-one) 
- ftp commands aren't working

Comment: Use a USB drive?  I know this isn't all too helpful, but it really sounds like you need to re-install your OS.

Comment: Hmm. What is question 302602? and 12786? Please [edit] your question and include proper  links.

Comment: Erm Click the link icon when editing your question? Press <Ctrl>+<L>? Read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)?.

Comment: [How to Get Online Without Using a Browser](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Online-Without-Using-a-Browser)

Comment: @DavidPostill  on the second step i get "connection closed by remote host"

Comment: Clearly you haven't tried all 4 methods yet. Method 2 says "Ask anyone who's reasonably tech-savvy: a friend, a coworker, a family member. The install files for most standard browsers are available on the developer websites: your friend can download Chrome directly from the Google site, for instance, Safari directly from Apple, or Firefox directly from Mozilla. If you have trouble finding the file, run a web search for "download [browser name]" to find the specific download page. Have your friend attach the file to an email, "

Comment: If I give you a link please take the time to read it all. Otherwise you are just wasting my time. Remember we are unpaid volunteers helping you for free, so please take the time to follow our advice.

Comment: And look at Josh's comment. You clearly have a working computer (otherwise you couldn't post here). Buy a thumbdrive and download an offline installer for the browser of your choice.

Comment: If you can't afford a thumbdrive email yourself the offline installer.

Comment: Out of curiosity... how are you posting on this site if you don't have a browser? If you have your phone you could download firefox or chrome binary on your phone and transfer it to your pc...

Comment: @DavidPostill As per site protocol, I did several google searches before posting a question. I had discovered your website, it showed up rather quickly. But thank you for pointing it out anyway. I appreciate your time.

Comment: @Darius Good question. I am posting on an iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to completely uninstall Internet Explorer from Windows 7; it can only be disabled so it doesn't *look* like it's installed.

To bring it back, go to the Control Panel and open Programs and Features.  Then, select **"Turn Windows features on or off"**.  Internet Explorer should be in the list.  Just check it and hit OK.  Once it's done it should prompt to restart the computer.

This assumes that you didn't use some kind of hack tool to remove it.  If that's what you did then you'll have to download a browser *somehow*, either on another computer with a USB flash drive (the easiest way), or use FTP to grab it from Mozilla or wherever.  You said you tried FTP but you didn't say exactly what the problem was.

Comment: It is then neccesary to restart the computer - that took me a while to figure out! Please add that to your answer.

Comment: If you had removed IE entirely, I'm wondering if running Windows Update would get it back for you?

Answer (score 8):

Just use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). It's a package manager for Windows, just like apt is for Linux.

Install it using this command in prompt:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin
```

It's useful to enable Global confirmations:

```
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
```

Then, all you have to do is type in prompt:

```
choco install googlechrome
```

And it's done. Simple, easy and fast!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a vanilla Windows 7 installation, you have at least PowerShell 2.0. [It can download files](https://superuser.com/a/362156/219095), although slightly complicated:

> If you just need to retrieve a file, you can use the [DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object:
>
> ```
> $client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
> $client.DownloadFile($url, $path)
> ```
>
> Where `$url` is a string representing the file's URL, and `$path` is representing the local path the file will be saved to.
>
> Note that `$path` must include the file name; it can't just be a directory.

It would be written like that:

```
$client.DownloadFile("https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/47.0.1/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2047.0.1.exe", "D:\\Firefox Setup.exe")
```

Note how backslashes need to be escaped by a backslash. If it immediately displays an error message, check that the target location (`D:\` in my example) is writable by the current user.

Make sure to also read the other answers over there, because it’s a lot easier on PS 3.0.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this on 2 different versions of PowerShell and got the FullyQualifiedErrorID: DotNetMethodException

Comment: ...with the message being? You did create the object first, right?

Comment: Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" arguments: an exception occurred during a WebClient request. At line:1 charachter:21. CategoryInfo: Not specified: (:) [] , MethodInvocationException

Comment: It’s most likely a permission error or URL typo. Double check everything. If it still doesn’t work, update your question with the command you tried. You can also further inspect error messages using the built-in `$Error` array, like so: `$Error[0] | Format-List -Force`.

Answer (score 0):

Boot a live Linux disc

start a terminal

install wget:

```
sudo apt-get wget
```

Then download firefox

```
wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/47.0.1/win32/en-US/Firefox\ Setup\ 47.0.1.exe
```

Copy it to a memory stick and then onto the PC.
Or better still install Linux on the PC.

Answer (score -1):

open a cmd window

right click bottom left click "run" type "cmd" enter below line

curl –output ffs.exe   https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/73.0.1/win64/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2073.0.1.exe

Comment: Curl isn’t a feature of Windows 7 out of the box.